# Identify the button clicked in iOS storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I created two view with navigation bar, lets name them view1 and view2. In view1, I create 4 round rect buttons and the view will be changed to view2 when the user click one of them. But because I want to pass something from view2 to view1 and make some changes in view1, I want to know which button the user clicked. I searched it on internet, but still cannot find the solution.

**The most important thing is I am using storyboard to set the push action, so that there is no IBAction assigned in any button of 4. How can I still get the sender tag?**

Is there anyone experienced in this problem? How to identify which button the user clicked?

Thank you very much.

Comment: repost of [Identify the button clicked in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418973/identify-the-button-clicked-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

> How to identify which button the user clicked?

The function

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

includes information about what button was used. That's what the (id)sender part is for.